# A question about asymptotic notations with sums.

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove that $$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}} = \Theta(3^{n})$$

I'm pretty sure it's straightforward to prove that it's $\Omega(3^{n})$ but I'm not sure how to prove the $O(3^{n})$ part. Maybe with using square root and derivative.

Comment: Small observations: (1) if you think it's straightforward to do part of the problem, sketch your thoughts on hom; (2) if you see weird numbers like the year (2017), pretty good chance you can replace it with any constant of your choosing, and the proof will go the same way.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the upper bound,, note that
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}}
  &\leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}}
  \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{k}} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}}
  \\&= \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 2^k
  = (1+2)^n = 3^n
  \end{align}$$
  giving the upper bound. We used at the beginning the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) that 
  $$
  \binom{2k}{k} \leq \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{3k+1}}\leq \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{k}}.
  $$
- For the lower bound, we have that
  $$\begin{align}
  \sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k} \binom{2k}{k} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}}
  &
  \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k} \frac{2^{2k}}{2\sqrt{k}} \frac{ \sqrt{k}}{2^{k}}
  \\&= \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k} 2^k
  \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} 2^k - \frac{2017}{2}\binom{n}{n-2017} 2^n\\
  &= \frac{1}{2}(1+2)^n - \frac{2017}{2} \binom{n}{2017}2^n
  = \frac{3^n}{2} - \Theta(n^{2017}2^n) = \Theta(3^n)
  \end{align}$$
  giving the lower bound. There, we used the basic result for any *constant* $k$, $\binom{n}{k} = \Theta(n^k)$ when $n\to \infty$.

Comment: As a side comment, using Stirling formula you get that $\binom{2k}{k} \sim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$, from which, since the series diverge, theorems of comparison give you that $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2^k}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{2^{2k}}{\sqrt{k}}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2^k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k = \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$, from which, since $\sum_{k=n-2016}^n \binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2^k} = O( n^{2017} 2^n )$,

Comment: we get $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2017} \binom{n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\frac{\sqrt{k}}{2^k}\operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty} \frac{3^n}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$ (i.e., a stronger statement than just $\Theta(3^n)$).